# Windows work flow edit rule set xml through C#

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

We have an existing rule sets defined in our system which are huge in number. We need to take of some of them and build new rule sets. Instead of doing manually and editing each rule set, i would like to programmatically edit them and update rule set xml in database. I am able to retrieve condition and make changes but cant convert it back to rule set. Any inputs on achieving this.

```
foreach (var condition in ruleSets.Rules)
{
    System.Workflow.Activities.Rules.RuleCondition modifiedCondition;

    if (condition.Condition.ToString().Contains("example"))
    {
        //UNABLE TO ACHIEVE THIS.
        modifiedCondition= condition.Condition.ToString().Replace("example", "example2");
    }                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't rewrite the Condition simply by modifying its textual representation. You would need to modify the existing Condition or create a new Condition via [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.aspx).

[Kavita's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kavitak/archive/2006/10/12/tinkering-with-the-rules-om.aspx) has a basic tutorial on manipulating the rules via CodeDom.
See also [this forum discussion.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a1df77b-7cad-49f0-b6cf-4acd1063a80b/creating-wf-rules-from-codedom)